# Estimating the time complexity (Big O notation) for the given code

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, big-o

Please help to find the complexity of the given code. Is it O(N+N+N) or O(N^3) or something else? Please given explanation for my understanding. Thank you.

the code

```
def finder(arr1,arr2):
          
count={}

for x in arr1:
    if x in count.keys():
        count[x]+=1
    else:
        count[x]=1
    
for x in arr2:
    if x in count.keys():
        count[x]-=1
    else:
        count[x]=1

for key,num in count.items():
    if num != 0:
        return key

return ('equal arrays')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, first you need to understand what "N" actually is. In this case we can say N is the length of arr1 and then lets call "M" the length of arr2.

The first loop iterates through arr1 completely so it has a complexity of O(N) (the worst case always happens, it always iterates through all elements in the array).

The second loop iterates through arr2 completely so it has a complexity of O(M).

The third loop iterates through `count.items` which is basically the length of the array `count`. In the worst case, the biggest length this array could have is N+M (meaning it has all items from arr1 and arr2). So it has a complexity of O(N+M).

Now, if loops (lets say the first and second one) are nested like:

```
for x in arr1:
    for y in arr2:
         // ....
```

then for every iteration in the first loop, there are M iterations on the second loop. So we can say that there are N iterations of M iterations each. This means the complexity would be O(N*M) and O(N^2) in case N = M.

In the other case, the loops are not nested, they are just one after the other.

```
for x in arr1:
    // ....
for y in arr2:
    // ....
```

This means the algorithm has a complexity O(N) + O(M) or O(N+M) since it first iterates N times and then M times. You can keep only the biggest complexity so if N > M, you can reduce it to O(N).

Now you can now figure out how to find your algorithm's complexity taking into account the third loop!